# Selenium not finding an element

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to retrieve an element that I would like to click on. Here's the opening of the website with Selenium in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--dns-prefetch-disable')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
website = "https://www.agronet.gov.co/estadistica/Paginas/home.aspx?cod=4"
driver.get(website)  # loads the page
```

Then, I look for the element I'm interested in:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cmbDepartamentos"]')
```

which raises a `NoSuchElementException` error. When looking at the html source (`driver.page_source`), indeed "cmbDepartamentos" does not exist! and the text of the dropdown menu I am trying to locate which is "Departamentos:" does not exist either. How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
iframe=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="iframe"]//iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cmbDepartamentos"]').click()
```

**Notes:**

- The reason for `NoSuchElementException` error is that the element is
  inside an `iframe`. Unless you switch your driver to that `iframe`,
  the identification will not work.
- CTRL + F in the Dev Tools panel, then search for the `xpath` you
  defined in your script is always a good way to rule out issues with
  your `xpath` definition, as cause for `NoSuchElementException` error  (and in your case, the `xpath` is correct)
- You might want to consider adding a `WebdriverWait` for a complete load of the search area/iframe before attempting to find the "Departamentos" field

Comment: And how would I access the elements of the dropdown menu? I'm trying to access them through `driver.find_element_by_class_name("dx-scrollview-content").find_elements_by_class_name("dx-item dx-list-item")` but this returns an empty list

Comment: `departamentos=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cmbDepartamentos"]')
options=departamentos.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@role="option"]')` then you can click on any option for example `options[3].click()`